# Can't access parent directory through reverse proxy on subdomain

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

This is my current Nginx server block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<tenant>.+)\.mysalon\.test$;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_types      text/plain application/xml text/css application/javascript;
    gzip_min_length 1000;

    location / {
        expires $expires;

        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header                     x-Tenant $tenant;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;

        proxy_read_timeout                  1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout               1m;

        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000/subdomain/;

    }
}
```

It's a reverse proxy for `{tenant}.mysalon.test` to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/subdomain/`.

**The issue**: 
It works correctly, but it returns 404's for everything within  `{tenant}.mysalon.test/_nuxt/`, that's because `/_nuxt` does not live in the `/subdomain/` directory, but in the parent `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`.

So I added the following:

```
location ^~ /_nuxt/ {
       proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:3000/_nuxt/;
}
```

So that even on the subdomains, it can access `/_nuxt`.

However, this new location block makes the first location block inactive for some reason.

When visiting `{tenant}.mysalon.test` it returns `http://127.0.0.1:3000` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:3000/subdomain/`.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why your second `location` block breaks the workflow, I didn't see any problems with this config, but you can try to use single `location` block and append the `/subdomain` prefix to the requested URI inside this block if the requested URI doesn't start with `/_nuxt/`:

```
    location / {
        expires $expires;

        rewrite                             ^(?!/_nuxt)(/.*) /subdomain$1 break;

        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header                     x-Tenant $tenant;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;

        proxy_read_timeout                  1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout               1m;

        proxy_pass                          http://127.0.0.1:3000;

    }
```

Comment: Hey Ivan, thanks for your reply. I added your line, which makes the workflow work again. However, it still doesn't solve the issue. In my network tab, it still returns 404's for everything in 'http://subdomain.mysite.test/_nuxt//*'

Comment: @Acework Did you remove the second `location` block from your config?

Comment: Yes I did, can you briefly explain what your line practically does?

Comment: @Acework It is modifies the request URI, appends an `/subdomain` to it if it doesn't starts with `/_nuxt`. Since I didn't use any URI suffix in the `proxy_pass` directive, modified (or non-modified if started with `/_nuxt`) URI passed to the proxy server as is.